# Problem with a test method in Yii web services

Tags: php, web-services, yii

Is there anyone here who might be familiar with web services in the yii framework?

I declared the following test method:

```
/**
  * Send a single SMS message
  * 
  * @param string $username Username
  * @param string $password Password
  * @param string $identifier Valid Identifier to use
  * @param string $mobileNumber Mobile Number to send message to
  * @param string $message Message to send
  * @return string 'OK' on success, error message on failure
  * @soap
  */
 public function singleSms($username, $password, $identifier,$mobileNumber, $message){
  return "username=$username, pwd=$password, source=$identifier, mobno=$mobileNumber, msg=$message";
 }
```

But when I try to call this method I get the following response:

> −
>   
>   −
>   
>   WSDL
>   −
>   
>   SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://sms.chillnethosting.co.za/index.php?r=sms/webservice' : Start tag expected, '<' not found

The WSDL generates when I call my URL: [Web Service URL](http://sms.chillnethosting.co.za/index.php?r=sms/webservice)

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please provide a complete PoC. It seems your caller accesses SmsController::actionWebservice(), but I can't see any such class/method in your code. Beside that, your documentation is wrong regarding the return value, which makes me think you're really confused...

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared your web service action?

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/topics.webservice#declaring-web-service-action

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure out what the problem was.  It seems that the WSDL was cached in my browser.  The error I received was due to a typo I made earlier, but the browser cached it.

Thanks for all the replies.

Answer (score 0):

Another example of Yii web service -

http://rowsandcolumns.blogspot.com/2011/02/yii-web-service-and-php-soap-client.html

Comment: Did you accidentally create two accounts on Stack Overflow? You can follow the [instructions given here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregiste/73801#73801) to flag a moderator and combine your accounts so you'll have full edit privileges on your questions/answers.